# FusionChart chart update freezes chart

Tags: javascript, fusioncharts

My chart freezes when its data are updated and also when downloading chart to client. Below is my updating process.

```
 FusionCharts.setCurrentRenderer('JavaScript');
            FusionCharts.ready(function () {
                var chart = new FusionCharts({
                    type: "dragcolumn2d",
                    renderAt: "chartWeightAnalysis",
                    id: "dragChartId",
                    width: '100%',
                    height: '500',
                    dataSource: "compute/" +<?php echo       $_SESSION['MM_Username']; ?> + "renderChartDragColumn2d.xml",
                    dataFormat: "xmlurl",
                    events: {
                        'chartUpdated': function (evt, args) {
                            var diffWeight = args.startValue - args.endValue;
                            var resultXML = chart.getXMLData();
                            var result = JSON.stringify(chart.getData());//                                alert(chart.getData());
                            var newString = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
                            var weightBox = [];
                            var sum = 0;
                            var resultBox = [];
                            var allDataBox = [];
                            jQuery.each(newString, function (key, value) {
                                if (key !== 0 && key !== args.dataIndex) {
                                    weightBox.push(value[1]);
                                    sum += value[1];
                                }
                            });
                            for (var key in weightBox)
                            {
                                var ratio = (weightBox[key] * diffWeight / sum);
                                var newValue = ratio + weightBox[key];
                                resultBox.push(newValue);
                                allDataBox.push(weightBox[key], newValue);
                            }
                            var dataIndex = (args.dataIndex - 1) * 2;
                            allDataBox.splice(dataIndex, 0, args.startValue, args.endValue);
                            var matrix = listToMatrix(allDataBox, 2);
                            for (var key in matrix) {
                                resultXML = resultXML.replace('value="' + matrix[key][0] + '"', 'value="' + matrix[key][1] + '"');
                            }

                            UpdateChart(chart, resultXML);
                        }
                    }
                }).render();
            });
        }

       function UpdateChart(chart, resultXML) {
            chart.setXMLData(resultXML);
        }
```

[image: a busy cat]
<sub>(source: [soft-touchdigital.com](http://soft-touchdigital.com/images/errorChart.png))</sub>

Once it renders, it becomes unresponsive. what could be the issue?
Also exporting a chart to client causes it to freeze likewise.

Comment: It is very difficult for us to tell you at which point the chart freezes. You are also using JQuery. The best option is to step debug it and pin which process breaks it. Look for errors also.

Comment: Through your browsers developer tools. For Chrome look at this [link](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging)

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tooltip' of undefineds.dragUp @ fusioncharts.powercharts.js:416n @ fusioncharts.js:247O @ fusioncharts.js:324z @ fusioncharts.js:321

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer, I realized that the error was from the setChartData function in general, if you use a different **setChartData** type it become unresponsive. for instance in my about code, I used *datasouce: as a url to XML*(**setXMLUrl**  equivalent) and later wanted to update using **setXMLData** in turn created an error. Look at the update code; I used ajax to save the updated date to the ***same file*** (Important!!!).

```
            function UpdateChart(resultXML) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        async: false,
                        url: "app_processor.php",
                        data: {action: "DragChartUpdate", getXMLData: resultXML},
                        success: function (msg) {
                            if (msg !== 0)
                            {
                                chart.setXMLUrl("compute/" +<?php echo $_SESSION['MM_Username']; ?> + "renderChartColumn2d.xml");
                            }
                        }
                    });

                }
```

in my php file:

```
function DragChartUpdate($getXMLData) {
   if (isset($getXMLData)) {
      file_put_contents("compute/" . $_SESSION['MM_Username'] . "renderChartColumn2d.xml", "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>" . $getXMLData . "");
   } else {
      file_put_contents("compute/" . $_SESSION['MM_Username'] . "renderChartColumn2d.xml", "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>");
   }
 }
```